# UNIX C programming input re-direction command

Tags: c, unix, pipe, file-descriptor

I'm trying to implement the following simple UNIX command:

```
cat -n < file.txt
```

where file.txt contains simply an integer "5".

Im fine with output redirection, but this input redirection has me stumped. This is my attempt at emulating the above command:

```
int f_des[2];
char *three[]={"cat", "-n", NULL};

// Open a pipe and report error if it fails
if (pipe(f_des)==-1){
    perror("Pipe");
    exit(1);
}

int filed=open("file.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

//fork child
if(fork()==0){
    dup2(f_des[1], filed);
    close(f_des[0]);
 }

 //fork child
 if(fork()==0){
     dup2(f_des[0], fileno(stdin));
     close(f_des[1]);
     execvp(three[0], three);
 }
```

I get the following error:

```
cat: -: Input/output error
```

My thinking was that I send filed(the fd for the file) through the pipe, the other end of the pipe would gather the file's contents from the pipe as standard input, then I would execute "cat -n" with the file's contents sitting in standard input.

Comment: Why did you open the file in output mode? Why do you call fork() three times (second will run in both parent and child of first).

Comment: I think you should open the file in Read mode. And where do you use the variable "three"?

Comment: So the code is correct except i need to open the file differently? If so, what flags should i be using with open(). Ah, sorry, i meant to exit the process after close(f_des[0]);

Comment: I changed WRONLY to RDONLY, and exit()'d after close(f_des[0]), but  now it gives no output at all with the corrections :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't indicate the context.  If all you are wanting to do is implement `cat -n < file`, you can dispense with the `pipe` and `fork` entirely.

This should suffice:

```
filed = open("file.txt", O_RDONLY);
dup2(filed, 0);  // make file.txt be stdin.
close(filed);    
execvp(three[0], three);
```

If you are implementing this within another program and need to resume after the `cat` call, `fork` is necessary but you only need to call it once.  You don't need the `pipe`.

So you would do:

```
int ret;
if ((ret = fork()) == 0) {
    // in child
    // open file, dup2, execvp...
}

// in parent
wait(&ret); // wait for child to exit
// do other stuff...
```

`fork` clones a copy of the process.  It looks like the one you had before except for the PID and the return value from `fork`.

Checking the return value of fork() tells you whether that process is the child or the parent.

If the return value is zero, you are in the child.  Do what you like in the `if(ret == 0) {}` section.  In your case, you do `execvp` which eventually exits and takes the child with it.

If the return value is not zero, you are in the parent.  You will skip over the `if(ret == 0) {}` section.  You should `wait` on the child to exit before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get it now. I think i was over-thinking the problem.

Comment: Happy to be of service.